# Assign const pointer to pointer

Tags: c++

I have class of worker, each worker has an array of pointers to co workers that are also workers.

I want to overload += operator so I will be able to do the following: *worker1 += *worker2.

This opertion will add worker2 to array of coworkers of worker1, and worker1 to array of coworkers of worker2.
(worker1, worker2 are pointers).

Relevant Worker class structure:

```
class Worker{
private:
Worker** coWorkers
}
```

The function that I have tried to implement:

```
const Worker& Worker::operator+=(const Worker& other){

}
```

The problem is the "other" is const but "coWorkers" is not const so I can't do the following:

```
this->coWorkers[last] = &other;
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Remove the const: `const Worker& other` -> `Worker& other`

Comment: Tip: Use `std::vector` and stay far, far away from `new[]` if you can. Managing lists like `Worker**` is an absolute nightmare. This could be as easy as `coWorkers.push_back(other)`.

Comment: @NathanOliver is this still right implementation of this operator overloading?

Comment: I think your design is potentially confusing to users of the class. I suggest that your `operator +=` should not modify the `other` argument; that would be very unconventional.

Comment: Sometimes you [have to step a bit outside the regular bounds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jl0hMfqNQ-g). You should have a good reason to do it, though. If the object   `other` is being added to needs to change `other` in the future, you don't have much of a choice. You could  leave other `const` and then cast away the `const` later, but that's an even nastier surprise to folks expecting the program to keep the promise `const` made.

Comment: The big question is since the behaviour is not what one generally expects from `+=`, should `+=` be used?

Comment: A possible problem with the model: Assume worker1 is already working with worker3 and worker4.  What happens to those when worker2 is added?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. This fragment of code suggest you have more problems, but we can't point them out since there are not fully visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all modern C++ way to do so use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) instead of `Worker** coWorkers`.
I think in your case list is preferred because you don't know the exact number of coworkers during initialization, as well as container i.e. list of co-workers can be changed in time i.e. new coworkers added and someone rotated, switch company etc.

You can push back a worker to the list as shown in example bellow:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Worker {
public:
  typedef std::list< Worker >::const_iterator const_iterator;
  explicit Worker(const std::string& name):
    name_(name)
  {}
  Worker& operator+=(const Worker& coWorker)
  {
    coWorkers_.push_back(coWorker);
    return *this;  
  }
  const_iterator begin() const {
    return coWorkers_.cbegin();
  }
  const_iterator end() const {
    return coWorkers_.cend();
  }
  const std::string& name() const {
    return name_;
  }
private:
  std::string name_;
  std::list< Worker > coWorkers_;
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv) 
{    
  Worker boss("Cesar");
  boss += Worker("Augustus");
  boss += Worker("Antonius");
  boss += Worker("Brutus");

  std::cout << boss.name() << std::endl; 
  for(auto i: boss) {
    std::cout << i.name() << std::endl; 
  }
}
```

Check [output](https://godbolt.org/z/KGraaoj1n)